# How to Calculate percentage in my program

Tags: c

I have written a program which is basically a survey, and reads responses which the user responds too. At the end of my program, I want it to print the percentage of statements that had long responses. I have declared statements that are longer than 5 seconds to be long responses, and have made an alarm signal which identifies when that happens. Here is my code so far:

```
 int count = 0;
int num;
float per;
int main()
{
    num = 0;
    per = (count/num) *100;
    printf("percent: %f", per );
}
```

Comment: replace `(count/num) *100` with `100.0f * count / num`

Comment: now it outputs this: Thank you for completing the survey. The handler was called 2 times
percent: inf

Comment: Of course `"inf"`.  Hint: Review `num` usage.

Comment: @chux Okay so I have found a couple of errors! I realized I declare num as an int twice! So I removed one of those declarations... Also, I changed my calculation to     per = 100.0f * count / c; and received an output of -200.00. Not quite sure how that happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You divide by `0`.`num` is the variable you use for input. For unknown reason you divide with it in the end.

You have a counter for how many times the handler is called. Add another counter for how many times you have answered the survey and increase it in the main loop.

Something like this:

```
int noHandlerCalls=0;  // Because good variable names is good

void handler(int sig){
    noHandlerCalls++;
    ...
}

int main() 
{
    ...
    int noSurveyAnswers=0;

    while ( num != 0 ) {
        if (num == 5 )
            signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
        signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);
        alarm(2);
        printf("Enter a number\n");
        signal(SIGALRM, handler);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        noSurveyAnswers++;
    }
    ...
    printf("percent: %f", (100.0*noHandlerCalls)/noSurveyAnswers );
```

And btw. This is a good example of where it would be good to follow this guide before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

If you did, your question would contain only this code:

```
int count = 0;
int num;
float per;
int main()
{
    num = 0;
    per = (count/num) *100;
    printf("percent: %f", per );
}
```

This is pretty much smallest code possible that still reproduces the error you ask about, and at that stage, you would probably had figured it out on your own. :)

Comment: I'm trying to get it to print the percentage of statements that had long responses. ie) 1 response out of the three was more than 5 seconds long to respond, so I would calculate (1/3) * 100. It seems like I have messed up with my variables.

Comment: Awesome got it! Simply just did 3 statements with waiting on one for 5 seconds and got a percent of 33.3. Cheers.